# React setState in useEffect causes infinite render cycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

I'm trying to build a calculator that lets you see comparative ratio values. But with my current approach, when the user edits the `num1` or `num2`, it causes an infinite re-render of the calculated values. I can't work out how to avoid this as both calc1 and calc2 are dependent on the ratio, but also each other.

How would I achieve this using a functional component?

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  let [num1, setNum1] = useState(5);
  let [num2, setNum2] = useState(10);
  let [ratio, setRatio] = useState();

  let [calc1, setCalc1] = useState();
  let [calc2, setCalc2] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setRatio(num2 / num1);
  }, [num1, num2]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCalc1(calc2 / ratio);
  }, [calc2, ratio]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCalc2(calc1 * ratio);
  }, [calc1, ratio]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="number"
        value={num1}
        onChange={e => setNum1(e.target.value)}
      />{" "}
      is to{" "}
      <input
        type="number"
        value={num2}
        onChange={e => setNum2(e.target.value)}
      />
      <p>Ratio is {ratio} therefore</p>
      <input
        type="number"
        value={calc1}
        onChange={e => setCalc1(e.target.value)}
      />{" "}
      ={" "}
      <input
        type="number"
        value={calc2}
        onChange={e => setCalc2(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit magical-herschel-nu5r9]

Comment: isn't `useState` supposed to take a default value?

Comment: @lomse i  believe it defaults to undefined if no default is provided. This issue persists even if you use 0 as the missing defaults

Answer (score 0):

There is a circular dependency here, when `setCalc1` triggers then `calc1` changes, so the second `useEffect` triggers with `setCalc2` that will modify `calc2` that since is a dependency in the first `useEffect` will restart the loop, and so on.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setCalc1(calc2 / ratio);
  }, [calc2, ratio]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCalc2(calc1 * ratio);
  }, [calc1, ratio]);
```

you have to refactor your code in order to avoid that dependency, for example using an object that wraps calc1 and calc2

https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-forest-typwu

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes I understand that a change to the ratio causes this because both are in useeffect. But I don't know how to achieve the behaviour I'm after in a functional component. Perhaps I need to rephrase the question

Comment: check the example it could be helpful :)

Comment: Thanks Karim. I'm not sure its quite it - in the example when I type 10 in the last box, it enters 5. The last box should still say 10, and the one before it should be 5. Changing them at the same time, as in your useEffect example, causes unexpected behaviour

Comment: what about now?

Comment: Perfect! I had just got it working also by using the click handler rather than a useEffect for the secondary calculation; https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-lovelace-cqz2c. Very similar solution to yours. Thank you

Comment: glad you fixed it ;)